# How to add a fourth table column?

Tags: tables, formatting, templates

I am using a template for publishing a paper. There I have a code for making a table but I am not able to add another column to that table using that code.

The code is given below:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l
                       >{\raggedright}p{0.3\linewidth}
                       >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.3\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Year}&\textbf{ set 1}& \textbf{ set 2}\\
    \midrule
    1999& 5000, 200, 500& 300\\\midrule
    2005& 400& 340, 250\\\midrule
    2015& 370
    & 160\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}%
```

The expected table I want to create is given below:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
\begin{tabular}{lllc}
```

to set up three left-aligned columns, followed by one centered column.

---

A complete MWE (minimum working example) -- note that I've omitted 2 of the 3 `\midrule` directives contained in your sample code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{lllc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Set 1} & \textbf{Set 2} & \textbf{Group} \\
    \midrule
    1999 & 5000, 200, 500 & 300      & \textbf{A} \\
    2005 & 400            & 340, 250 & \textbf{B} \\
    2015 & 370            & 160      & \textbf{A} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```